# On the use of typedef keyword

Tags: c, stack, typedef

```
typedef int ElementType; 
struct SNode{
ElementType data;
struct SNode* next; 
};
typedef struct SNode SNode;
typedef struct SNode* LinkStack;
typedef struct SNode* Position;
```

What role does typedef play in the structure definition of this stack，or what is the keyword typedef used for？

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `typedef`? See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef or https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/typedef What specifically don't you understand?

Comment: They don't play any part in the definition of the `struct` itself. The last two are to hide the pointer to the `struct` behind a `typedef`, which isn't advisable. And why create the two types `LinkStack` and `Position` for the same thing? It makes it even more obscure.

Comment: I answered a duplicate of this a few days ago [at Codidact](https://software.codidact.com/posts/285573). You can probably skip the question and just read the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct SNode SNode;
```

is used to allow defining stack nodes as:

```
SNode node;
```

rather that

```
struct SNode node;
```

The namespaces for tags (of structs, unions and enums) and the identifiers (like typedef) are separated. Therefore one write:

```
struct X { ... };
typedef int X;
```

And everything works fine. The mentioned typedef adds an alias for `struct SNode` type to identifiers namespace.